# Двигать спрайт свайпами по экрану

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как двигать платформу по экрану свайпами в unity3d, или просто перемещать её в то место где стоит палец (по оси Х)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код простого движения кнопками:

```
    void FixedUpdate(){
         float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }
```

Comment: В юнити есть обработка прикосновение (тачей) и у этих тачей есть фазы.....https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html ........ думаю надо следить за тачем с фазой `Moved` и узнавать в какие координаты полетел тач...(а то может по оси Y было движение) и уже делать то что вы хотите: перемещать именно в те же координаты или же просто задетектить перемещение пальца, но скорость платформы оставить прежней.... например если перемещение тача было больше чем 1.5f (в ту или иную сторону от того места где был до этого) - значит двигать платформу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы узнать местоположение вашего пальца, следует использовать класс `Input`. В нём присутствует массив `Input.touches`. Переводите точки из массива при помощи класса `Camera` используя метод `SreenPointsToRay`. После, полученные данные переводите в `RayCast`.

Пример

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyProjectName.Input
{
    using Input = UnityEngine.Input;

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработчик взаимодействий.
    /// </summary>
    public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0f)
                return;

            Vector2[] inputPoints = new Vector2[0];

#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE // Стационарный обработчик. (ПК).

            if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                return;

            inputPoints = new Vector2[1];
            inputPoints[0] = Input.mousePosition;

#elif UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_TIZEN || UNITY_WP_8 || UNITY_WP_8_1 // Мобильный обработчик.

            inputPoints = new Vector2[Input.touchCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
                inputPoints[i] = Input.touches[i].position;

#endif

            if (inputPoints.Length == 0)
                return;

            ToRaycast(inputPoints);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Перевод точек в Raycats.
        /// </summary>
        private void ToRaycast(Vector2[] inputPoints)
        {
            RaycastHit raycast = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(inputPoint), Vector2.zero); // В дальнейшем можно использовать эти данные. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе. `ToRaycast`, можете проводить все необходимые действия.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь свайпы НЕ НУЖНЫ.

Да и рейкаст, собственно, тоже...

1. Тебе нужно заблокировать по Y оси твой перетаскиваемый обьект
2. Тебе нужна реализация Drag() -- например как-то так:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   [RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]

   public class Drag : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private Vector3 screenPoint;
       private Vector3 offset;

       void OnMouseDown()
       {

           offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
       }

       void OnMouseDrag()
       {
           Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
           Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
           transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, curPosition, Time.deltaTime);
       }
   }
   ```

Не уверен что код отработает как нужно, но идея подхода 100% должна быть именно такой.

---

Или же реализация драга которая сработает только по оси X экрана телефона.

Так же может быть полезно погуглить по ключевикам: `IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler`

для более коректной реализации.